# AWS ECS Tutorial Not Loading Over Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Is anyone able to successfully follow the AWS Developer tutorial for **[AWS ECS Tutorial: Creating a cluster with a Fargate Linux task using the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI_Fargate.html)** and load the fargate-app registered task's over public IP?

Unclear why it fails to load, when it could be simple.

Comment: Please share the error logs, the configuration of your images, task-def etc. Not very helpful to debug if you post a generic description